# Tamei what causes it?

Tags: commentaries, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

To sum things up quickly as an example: If a woman is in her state of nidah Vayikra 15 teaches that what she touches or if something/someone is touching her, or if someone is touching that which has touched her becomes tamei.

So what is it that's being transfered and causes someone or a thing to become tamei?

The same could be applied to other situations/cases in which someone is in a certain state and causes other things/people to become tamei.

And do people really get Tamei these days?

Answer (score 1):

[The Hebrew Wikipedia article](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%98%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%94#%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%98%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%94) gives two approaches to understanding Tumah.

> הטומאה כמציאות קיימת 1
>
> גישה אחת סוברת, שהטומאה שחלה על אדם או חפץ היא מציאות ממשית – ישות
>   רוחנית מסוימת, אף כי היא בלתי נראית ואינה מושגת לחושים. על פי דרך זו
>   ניתן אף לומר, שההלכות האמורות בטומאה נועדו רק לחשוף את המציאות הקיימת
>   ממילא בטבעו הרוחני של העולם. לפי השקפה זו, רוח הטומאה עלולה לגרום
>   נזקים לנפשו של מי שבא עמה במגע, ושמירת הטהרה מצילה את האדם מנזק זה.
>   ביטויים לתפיסה זו ניתן למצוא בכתבי כמה מן הראשונים.[5]
>
> 1] The impurity exists as reality
>
> One approach holds that the impurity that applies to a person or
>   object is an actual reality - a certain spiritual entity, though
>   invisible and unattainable. According to this approach one can even
>   say that the said laws in impurity are intended only to reveal the
>   reality that already exists in the spiritual nature of the world.
>   According to this view, the spirit of impurity may cause damage to the
>   soul of those who come into contact with it, and the preservation of
>   the purification saves the person from this damage. Expressions of
>   this perception can be found in the writings of several of the
>   Rishonim.

Note that even though the impurity is a reality it is only a spiritual entity – not given to detection by the human senses.

> 2 הטומאה כרעיון סמלי
>
> גישה שנייה סוברת, שאין צורך להניח את דבר קיומה הממשי של רוח טומאה,
>   ועניין הטומאה הוא ריחוק, לרוב כביטוי סמלי של רעיון כלשהו. כך סבר
>   הרמב"ם, שהטומאה איננה ישות רוחנית מציאותית, אלא הגדרה הלכתית גרידא,
>   וכפי שכתב בסיום "ספר טהרה" בחיבורו הגדול משנה תורה: "דבר ברור וגלוי
>   שהטומאות והטהרות גזירות הכתוב הן, ואינן מדברים שדעתו של אדם מכרעת
>   אותן, והרי הן מכלל החוקים. וכן הטבילה מן הטומאות - מכלל החוקים היא,
>   שאין הטומאה טיט או צואה שתעבור במים, אלא גזירת הכתוב היא... כיוון שטבל
>   - טהור, ואף על פי שלא נתחדש בגופו דבר." (משנה תורה לרמב"ם, ספר טהרה, הלכות מקואות, פרק י"א, הלכה י"ב)
>
> 2] Impurity as a symbolic idea
>
> A second approach holds that there is no need to assume the actual
>   existence of a spirit of impurity. The essence of impurity is a
>   symbolic expression of the idea of distancing. Thus Maimonides
>   believed that impurity is not a real spiritual entity, but rather a
>   purely halakhic definition, and as he wrote at the end of Sefer Tahara
>   in his great book Mishneh Torah: "It is abundantly clear that the
>   impurities and the purity are the decrees of Scripture. And they are
>   beyond human understanding -  they are part of the decrees (of the
>   Almighty). And the immersion (in a mikvah) for the impurity – is also
>   one of the decrees. Impurity is not mud or feces that will be removed
>   by the water, but it is the decree of Scripture is ... that after he
>   has immersed he becomes pure and even though nothing has changed in
>   his body. "(Mishneh Torah of Maimonides, , Chapter 11, Halacha 12).

Here, impurity is not even a spiritual reality.

Therefore, the transfer of tumah is the transfer of either a spiritual reality or the transfer of the decrees of the Almighty.

Tumah finds its expression in our days through the laws of Family Purity and [Niddah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niddah#Ritual_purity_aspect) and through the [Prohibition of Kohen defilement by the dead] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prohibition_of_Kohen_defilement_by_the_dead#Modern_applications) .

Comment: In the quote the rambam says tuma is a decree that we don't know the reason for. He doesn't say it doesn't have a spiritual reality.

Comment: Along the lines of @ykay 's comment, I believe the Rambam writes elsewhere that he himself was personally strict to keep *takanas ezra* (immersing before prayer/learning) even though it was no longer halacha, suggesting the Rambam also assumed tumah/tahara correspond to a metaphysical reality beyond actual practical halacha.

Comment: @ykay Your comment is really to the author of the Hebrew Wikipedia article which I quoted. He does not show in this extract, I agree, how he deduces his opinion about the Rambam. You may like to read the rest of what he says in that part of the article (and I admit I have not) and post a comment there.

Answer (score 0):

Rambam explains the reason for the laws of ritual impurity in Guide for the Perplexed 3:47.

> THE precepts of the twelfth class are those which we have enumerated
>   in the section on "Purity" (Sefer tohorah). Although we have mentioned
>   their use in general, we will here offer an additional explanation,
>   and [first] fully discuss the object of the whole class, and then show
>   the reason of each single commandment, as far as we have been able to
>   discover it. I maintain that the Law which was revealed to Moses, our
>   Teacher, and which is called by his name, aims at facilitating the
>   service and lessening the burden, and if a person complains that
>   certain precepts cause him pain and great trouble, he cannot have
>   thought of the habits and doctrines that were general in those days.
>   Let him consider the difference between a man burning his own son in
>   serving his god, and our burning a pigeon to the service of our God.
>   Scripture relates, for even their sons and their daughters they burn
>   in the fire to their gods (Deut. xii. 31). This was the way in which
>   the heathen worshipped their gods, and instead of such a sacrifice we
>   have the burning of a pigeon or a handful of flour in our worship. In
>   accordance with this fact, the Israelites, when disobedient, were
>   rebuked by God as follows: "O My people, what have I done unto thee?
>   and wherein have I wearied thee? Testify against me" (Mic. vi. 3).
>   Again, "Have I been a wilderness unto Israel? a land of darkness?
>   Wherefore say my people, We are miserable; we will come no more unto
>   thee" (Jer. ii. 31); that is to say, Through which of the commandments
>   has the Law become burdensome to the Israelites, that they renounce
>   it? In the same manner God asks the people, "What iniquity have your
>   fathers found in me, that they are gone far from me?" etc. (ibid. ii.
>   5). All these passages express one and the same idea.
>
> This is the great principle which you must never lose sight of.
>   **After having stated this principle, I repeat that the object of the Sanctuary was to create in the hearts of those who enter it certain
>   feelings of awe and reverence, in accordance with the command, "You
>   shall reverence my sanctuary" (Lev. xix. 30). But when we continually
>   see an object, however sublime it may be, our regard for that object
>   will be lessened, and the impression we have received of it will be
>   weakened. Our Sages, considering this fact, said that we should not
>   enter the Temple whenever we liked, and pointed to the words: "Make
>   thy foot rare in the house of thy friend" (Prov. xxv. 17). For this
>   reason the unclean were not allowed to enter the Sanctuary, although
>   there are so many kinds of uncleanliness, that [at a time] only a few
>   people are clean. For even if a person does not touch a beast that
>   died of its own accord (Lev. xi. 27), he can scarcely avoid touching
>   one of the eight kinds of creeping animals (ibid. 29, seq.), the dead
>   bodies of which we find at all times in houses, in food and drink, and
>   upon which we frequently tread wherever we walk; and, if he avoids
>   touching these, he may touch a woman in her separation (ibid. xv. 18),
>   or a male or female that have a running issue (ibid. ver. 1, seq. and
>   25, seq.), or a leper (ibid. xiii. 46), or their bed (ibid. xv. 5).
>   Escaping these, he may become unclean by cohabitation with his wife,
>   or by pollution (ibid. 15), and even when he has cleansed himself from
>   any of these kinds of uncleanliness, he cannot enter the Sanctuary
>   till after sunset; but not being enabled to enter the Sanctuary at
>   night time, although he is clean after sunset, as may be inferred from
>   Middot and Tamid, he is again, during the night, subject to becoming
>   unclean either by cohabiting with his wife or by some other source of
>   uncleanliness, and may rise in the morning in the same condition as
>   the day before. All this serves to keep people away from the
>   Sanctuary, and to prevent them from entering it whenever they liked.
>   Our Sages, as is well known, said, "Even a clean person may not enter
>   the Sanctuary for the purpose of performing divine service, unless he
>   takes previously a bath." By such acts the reverence [for the
>   Sanctuary] will continue, the right impression will be produced which
>   leads man, as is intended, to humility.**
>
> The easier the diffusion of uncleanliness is, the more difficult and
>   the more retarded is its purification. Most easily is uncleanliness
>   communicated by the dead body to those who are under the same roof,
>   especially to relatives. The purification can only be completed by
>   means of the ashes of the red heifer, however scarce it may be, and
>   only in seven days (Num. xix. 11). The uncleanness caused by a woman
>   having running issue or during her separation is more frequent than
>   that caused by contact with unclean objects: seven days are therefore
>   required for their purification (Lev. xv. 19, 28), whilst those that
>   touch them are only unclean one day (ibid. vii. 18). Males or females
>   that are unclean through running issue, and a woman after childbirth,
>   must in addition bring a sacrifice, because their uncleanness occurs
>   less frequently than that of women in their separation. **All these
>   cases of uncleanliness, viz., running issue of males or females,
>   menstruations, leprosy, dead bodies of human beings, carcases of
>   beasts and creeping things, and issue of semen, are sources of dirt
>   and filth. We have thus shown that the above precepts are very useful
>   in many respects. First, they keep us at a distance from dirty and
>   filthy objects; secondly, they guard the Sanctuary; thirdly, they pay
>   regard to an established custom (for the Sabeans submitted to very
>   troublesome restrictions when unclean, as you will soon hear);
>   fourthly, they lightened that burden for us; for we are not impeded
>   through these laws in our ordinary occupations by the distinction the
>   Law makes between that which is unclean and that which is clean. For
>   this distinction applies only in reference to the Sanctuary and the
>   holy objects connected with it: it does not apply to other cases. "She
>   shall touch no hallowed thing, nor come into the Sanctuary" (Lev. xii.
>   4). Other persons [that do not intend to enter the Sanctuary or touch
>   any holy thing], are not guilty of any sin if they remain unclean as
>   long as they like, and eat, according to their pleasure, ordinary food
>   that has been in contact with unclean things.** But the practice of
>   the Sabeans, even at present general in the East, among the few still
>   left of the Magi, was to keep a menstruous woman in a house by
>   herself, to burn that upon which she treads, and to consider as
>   unclean every one that speaks with her: even if a wind passed over her
>   and a clean person, the latter was unclean in the eyes of the Sabeans.
>   See the difference between this practice and our rule, that "whatever
>   services a wife generally does to her husband, she may do to him in
>   her separation"; only cohabitation is prohibited during the days of
>   her uncleanness. Another custom among the Sabeans, which is still
>   widespread, is this: whatever is separated from the body, as hair,
>   nail, or blood, is unclean; every barber is therefore unclean in their
>   estimation, because he touches blood and hair; whenever a person
>   passes a razor over his skin he must take a bath in running water.
>   Such burdensome practices were numerous among the Sabeans, whilst we
>   apply the laws that distinguish between the unclean and the clean only
>   with regard to hallowed things and to the Sanctuary. ([Friedlander translation](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp183.htm), emphasis added.)

Essentially, there is nothing inherently bad or wrong or spiritually deficient about ritual impurity. It is either a physical uncleanness, or a legal state of being designed to keep one from frequenting the Holy Temple.

[R. Yosef Bechor Shor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_ben_Isaac_Bekhor_Shor) (Exodus 15:26) also explains ritual impurity as actually being physical uncleanness, and God was doing us a favor by keeping us from these sources of defilement, as it prevents disease.

> כמו שהרופא שומר מאכל האדם ומתקנו שלא יבא עליו שום חולי כן אני אשמור
>   אותך שלא תבא לידי חולי כמו שהמתקתי לך המים שלא יזיקו לך וכן הזהיר
>   הקב"ה על ישראל נבילות שקצים ורמסים ובהמות טמאות ועופות טמאים ודגים
>   טמאים שהם מזיקים וממאיסים גופו של אדם כי האוכלם נמאס ומזוהם וגם הפרישם
>   מנגעים ומזבין ומזבות ויולדות ונידות ומנבלת אדם ובהמה ומנגעי אדם ובתים
>   ובגדים שכל אילו מביאין אותם לידי זיהום כי כל דבר שהכתוב קוראו טמא
>   מיאוס הוא כי טמא לשון מיאוס כמו שכתוב ביחזקאל והיא בגללי צאת האדם
>   תעוגינה [לעיניהם ויאמר ה'] ככה יאכלו [בני] ישראל [את] לחמם טמא בגוים
>   אלמא טמא לשון מיאוס וכן אמרו רבותי' כל האוכל פת בלא ניגוב ידים כאילו
>   אוכל לחם טמא מפני שהוא מאוס כשידיו לחים הלחם נמאס מליחלוחית מי ידיו
>   ומביאין זה הפסוק לראיה ככה יאכלו [בנ"י] את לחמם טמא שהוא לשון מיאוס
>   וזהו כי אני ה' רופאך שאפרישך מכל המיאוסין הללו כי המיאוס מביא את האדם
>   לידי חליות וכן הוא אומר וברך את לחמך ואת מימיך והסירותי מחלה מקרבך
>   ואינו אומר כי אני ה' רופאך שתהיה חולה וארפאך דאם כך הוי קללה